# Splitting string into substring in Java

Tags: java, string, split, substring

I have one string and I want to split it into substring in Java, originally the string is like this

```
Node( <http://www.mooney.net/geo#wisconsin> )
```

Now I want to split it into substring by (#), and this is my code for doing it

```
String[] split = row.split("#");

String word = split[1].trim().substring(0, (split[1].length() -1));
```

Now this code is working but it gives me

```
    "wisconsin>"
```

the last work what I want is just the work "wisconsin" without ">" this sign, if someone have an idea please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Java1.7 DOC for String class**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Actually it gives you output as `"wisconsin> "` **(include space)**

Make `subString()` as

```
String word = split[1].trim().substring(0, (split[1].length()-3));
```

**Then you will get output as**

`wisconsin`

[**Tutorials Point**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm) String subString() method reference

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
String split[] = row.split("#|<|>");
```

which delivers a `String` array like this,

```
{"http://www.mooney.net/geo", "wisconsin"}
```

Get the last element, at index `split.length()-1`.

Answer (score 1):

String string = "Enter parts here";

String[] parts = string.split("-");

String part1 = parts[0];

String part2 = parts[1];

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please use markdown to format your code, otherwise it is harder to understand. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

you can just split like you did before once more (with > instead of #) and use the element [0] istead of [1]

Answer (score -1):

You can just use replace like.

> word.replace(char oldChar, char newChar)

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

You can use Java String Class's subString() method.

Refer to [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm).